# A way to change program audio output based on what monitor it is on?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, speakers, audio-output

## The question in short:

**is it possible to have application independent audio output *depending on what monitor the application is currently on***, and change it automatically on the fly without manual sound/audio output confirmation.

### Detailed explanation

I have the current setup with my PC (Windows 7 x64):

- **Monitor A**: for general PC-usage
- **Speakers** that output audio from the PC (naturally)
- **Monitor B**: HDTV that has inbuilt speakers, connected to the PC with HDMI (with sound)

For an example scenario:

1. I have 2 programs open that output audio (for example. a media player (**MPC**) and a windowed **game**)
2. The **MPC** is open on monitor **A**, the **game** is on monitor **B**

And this would be the required end result:

1. The audio output from the game is heard from the HDTV **inbuilt speakers** (through the HDMI output, of course)
2. The audio output from MPC is heard form the **PC speakers**
3. **When dragging the game from monitor B to A (or vice versa) the audio output would change according to what monitor the source (game/MPC) software is run on**

Please note that these are **NOT** acceptable solutions:

- Manual/quickswitch apps for audio output
- Manually changing app X audio output to desired output
- "just change it when you need it, it's not that hard"

I use apps (browsers, media players, Steam etc.) that I want to have different outputs depending on what monitor the application is currently on. So far I have only found quickswitchers to change the whole systems default output to A or B, or an app that does allow app-independent audio outputs, but it does require manual interaction.

Is there any software that does this? Is there some way I could make this reality? Linux answers are welcome too.

(Question posted in superuser.com since I figured it was an advanced user -type question)